# Конвертация dict -> defaultdict

Tags: python, dict

Я новичок в python, возникла такая потребность: перевести `dict` в `defaultdict`:

```
dict = {"a": ["b", "c"],
        "b": ["c"]}
```

Каким образом можно создать `defaultdict`? Пользоваться методом `extend`, или можно как-то проще?

Comment: `dict = defaultdict(функция, dict)` или в чём проблема?

Comment: @andreymal, а что такое функция? непонятно что в моем случае использовать в качестве первого аргумента

Answer (score 3):

```
d = {"a": ["b", "c"], "b": ["c"]}

ddict = defaultdict(list, d)
```

Первым параметром `defaultdict` должен передаваться объект, вызов которого через круглые скобки задает начальное значение для ключа. Это может быть функция (которая будет при вызове создавать нужное значение) или имя класса (объект которого будет создаваться при необходимости задать начальное значение для ключа).

Т.к. у вас в данном случае значениями являются списки, то тут логично создавать пустой список как значение по умолчанию - для этого передаем `list` как первый параметр.